# Magento 2 Google Analytics not showing

Tags: magento2.3, google-analytics

For some reason Google Analytics code isn't showing up in the frontend.
The module appears to be working, but all that appears is this:

```
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
```

I've checked the values:

```
isCookieRestrictionModeEnabled = 0
getCurrentWebsiteId = 1
IS_USER_ALLOWED_SAVE_COOKIE = user_allowed_save_cookie  
getPageTrackingData = {"optPageUrl":"","isAnonymizedIpActive":false,"accountId":"UA-xxxx-1"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Following : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/google-universal-analytics.html

Comment: yes, it is set up according to the docs, the block shows up but there is no content between the begin and end tags for some reason...

Comment: try this mageants [magento 2 google analytics extension](https://www.mageants.com/google-analytics-for-magento-2.html) and if face any issues they provide quick support